# wp_get_recent_posts in index.php

Tags: wordpress, posts

I need to use the_title() and other functions in the template-part!!

In my index.php i have:

```
$args=array(
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$recent_posts =wp_get_recent_posts( $args,ARRAY_A);
foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {

    setup_postdata($post);
    echo "<h1>$post[ID]</h1>";
    the_title();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'list' );
}
```

The echo shows correct post-ID´s.
But  ,  the_title() : always displays "hello world" ( first post ),
thus, my template-part has only the first Post Object which is not from the $recent_posts.

What´s wrong?

Comment: The template-part is using many the_ functions like the_title() ... I don´t want to rewrite that to echo $data["title"]

Answer (score 0):

Try below foreach code:

```
foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {

setup_postdata($post);
echo "<h1>$post[ID]</h1>";
echo $post["post_title"];
get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'list' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $post["post_title"];
```

More Info :
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts

Answer (score 0):

First of all, pass some more parameter in your post query like,

```
'post_type'        => 'post',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
```

to clarify from which post-type you want to display your post.
inside the loop change,

```
the_title();
```

into,

```
$post->post_title or $post['post_title']
```

depends on data getting through object or an array.

I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it.
For those that understood my real question:

Don´t use wp_get_recent_posts.
Instead:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=10' ); 
while ($the_query -> have_posts()) {
    $the_query -> the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'list' );
}
```